# Bootstrap 4 grid-only css, using bootstrap media queries in my scss style

Tags: sass, grid, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm pretty much new to Bootstrap 4 and Sass\SCSS,I wanted to use the new grid and style the rest of my website on my own using SCSS, so I downloaded bootstrap source, compiled bootstrap-grid.scss (which is only the grid plus some variables and mixins), now the question that pops in my mind is : How do I use bootstrap's media queries screen sizes with my own style? Is there a particular mixin/way to call the breakpoints? Or since I'm using the grid only I have to configure media queries myself?

My idea was that there probably would be a mixin that allows me to do for example :

```
.my_class {
  color: red;
  +mobile {
  color: blue;
  }
}
```

Does bootstrap have something like this? I have to do it on my own? How do you proceed when working with the grid only?

Answer (score 0):

Yep. There's many Sass options in Bootstrap 4. You can read about them in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#sass-mixins).